# Getting values from a nested list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

```
nest_list_of_dicts = [[{"dictionary": 'AAPL', 'A': 1.1, 'B': 1.2, 'C': 1.3}, {"dictionary": 'NFLX', 'A': 1.4, 'B': 1.5, 'C': 1.6}],
                      [{"dictionary": 'AAPL', 'A': 2.1, 'B': 2.2, 'C': 2.3}, {"dictionary": 'NFLX', 'A': 2.4, 'B': 2.5, 'C': 2.6}],
                      [{"dictionary": 'AAPL', 'A': 3.1, 'B': 3.2, 'C': 3.3}, {"dictionary": 'NFLX', 'A': 3.4, 'B': 3.5, 'C': 3.6}]]
```

Hello,
I'm trying to create a function which can append all of AAPL's 'A' and 'B' values in seperate lists then to find the mean average of both list's. And the same for NFLX.

I'm trying to find a solution which could handle these list's expanding with more dictionaries in the future, the nested list's will always have the same amount of dictionaries and KEYS.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encourage you to look into pandas. You can convert the list of dictionaries into a dataframe by using list comprehension and then concatenate your list of frames together. Once you have a dataframe you can groupby your key and find the mean of each column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(l) for l in nest_list_of_dicts]).groupby('dictionary').mean()

              A    B    C
dictionary               
AAPL        2.1  2.2  2.3
NFLX        2.4  2.5  2.6
```